# Creating a new maven goal to run jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, maven, jasmine

This feels like it should have a really simple answer, but for some reason I can't work it out this morning...

I have some Jasmine tests in my app.  I run the tests as part of my maven test goal.

However, I'd like to be able to run them in isolation, and I can't work out how to do this.

The jasmine plugin is set up like so:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2-beta-5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            ...
        </plugin>
```

Ideally I'd like to

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2-beta-5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                        <goal>jasmine</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            ...
        </plugin>
```

And execute `mvn jasmine`. This doesn't work (Symbol not found).

What do I need to do to make this work?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out... (with a little help)

```
mvn jasmine:test
```

It was obviously just a little bit early in the morning ;)